# Poner True o False en una lista PYTHON

Tags: python, lista, poo, booleano

Estoy haciendo una lista de N cantidad de números (la cual necesito que quede True, False, True, False....) La manera en la que la hice fue crear una lista de números, y debajo de esta convertir valores pares a True e impares a False. Pero me sale

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Melanie Solano\Documents\LISTAS_PYTHON\4.py.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(booleans(10))
  File "c:\Users\Melanie Solano\Documents\LISTAS_PYTHON\4.py.py", line 14, in booleans
    if i in range(n+1)%2==0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'range' and 'int'
PS C:\Users\Melanie Solano\Documents\LISTAS_PYTHON>
```

Aquí enseño mi código ( sí o sí debo empezar con función)

```py
def booleans(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(n+1):
        lst.append(i)
        if i %2==0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return(lst)

    print(booleans(10))
```

Comment: La condición solo debe ser `if i%2==0`

Comment: También podrías hacer `lst = [i%2==0 for i in range(n+1)]`

Comment: Hola Christian! Ya no me da error, pero solo me sale un dato (true)... lo ideal es que sea la cantidad de datos N. ¿Cómo podría hacer para que tome los datos de la lista hasta el n que le ponga?
def booleans(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(n+1):
        lst.append(i)
        if i %2==0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return(lst)

print(booleans(10))

Comment: Ohh, no sé por qué se ve así de feo:(, no me deja ponerlo en código. Ya lo puse en el código de la pregunta principal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te está pasando es que el return termina de ejecutar la función (y con ello cualquier bucle).

#### Solución

La solución habitual sería crear un [generador](https://ellibrodepython.com/yield-python) usando funciones con `yield [valor]`  o [comprensiones de generador](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/).

```
def booleans(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        if i %2==0:
            yield True
        else:
            yield False

    # convertimos el generador a lista.
    print(list(booleans(10)))
```

Cuando `i % 2 == 0` devuelve True, tu función debe devolver True, cuando devuelve False, tu función debe devolver False. Por lo que podríamos convertir esto:

```
if i %2==0:
    yield True
else:
    yield False
```

En esto:

```
yield (i % 2 == 0)
```

#### Solución básica

Pero si estás haciendo algo academico y no entiendes o no llegaste a ver generadores ni comprensiones, simplemente evita hacer return hasta que la lista esté llena con los valores que esperas.

```
def booleans(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(n+1):
        if i %2==0:
            lst.append(True)
        else:
            lst.append(False)
    return(lst)

    print(booleans(10))
```

Si seguimos el principio que vimos al final de que podemos agregar el resultado de una comparación directamente a la lista, tu código se reduce a:

```
def booleans(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(n+1):
        lst.append(i % 2 == 0)
    return(lst)

    print(booleans(10))
```